# Creating XML using VTD XMLModifier

Tags: xml, vtd-xml

Would you recommend using XMLModifier to generate XML from ground up? Or just use whatever java has like XMLWriter?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use XMLWrite to composing XML from scratch. Use XMLModifier to incrementally update XML.. Or use string concatenation  to generate XML from scratch